# Video Clip as a Animated Picture

Tags: video-editing

I'm looking for a tool that can record what you do on the computer screen and then you can use it as a animated picture (the picture below).

What is the name of the tool in order to do it?

Info:
*I doesn't matter if the software is open source or commercial.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: For what OS should it be?

Answer (score 1):

[Screen to GIF](https://www.screentogif.com/) can record your screen and edit animations then sabe them as either GIF or video files.

[GIFCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) can also record with basic editing capabilities

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a tool which can do captureing and exprot it as gif but...

You can open video files in Adobe Photoshop. It will open the video in the "video timeline". With "Save for Web" you can export a gif.

So you could use any common screen capturer to generate the video file.

Answer (score 0):

A free program available for Windows, Mac and Linux is [Open Broadcast Studio](https://obsproject.com/) which will record screen activity. It creates conventional video files, which you would then resize for your screen purposes.

Your objective is a bit unclear, as you've not indicated what program you would use to display the video. There are stand-alone video players such as VLC player which will play the OBS-created files.

Note that the above referenced program can also be used for live streaming, and much of the material is presented from that frame of reference.